# Custom NSPredicate in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nspredicate

I have an NSTableView whose columns are bound to a subclass of NSArrayController.  Each entry of the 'value' column is a list of file paths (in the model), in particular, PATH and PYTHONPATH for an app.

What I want is to control edits to these values to as they are made, to ensure that each of the paths on the list is a valid one.  Since I'm using bindings, I'm thinking I should write some kind of NSPredicate but I'd like to have it use a function that I define to do the filter, since the testing is a bit complex.  How do you use a custom function with an NSPredicate?

Or should I consider another approach?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I have figured out how to make the string containing filepaths into an expression that evaluates to what I want, using a category on NSString that adds the method `validate`. But I still don't know how to get it into a filter predicate.

```
NSString *s = @"~:~/Desktop";
NSExpression *f = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:s];
NSExpression *e = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:f
                                         selectorName:@"validate" 
                                            arguments:nil];
```

I guess this would basically be a filter predicate that always spits out what the expression evaluates to..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
NSString *s = @"~:~/Desktop";
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FUNCTION(%@, 'validate') == YES", s];
```

Or if you have an array of strings that you want to filter to find all the ones that pass validation:

```
NSArray *array = ...; //your array of strings needing validation
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FUNCTION(SELF, 'validate') == YES"];
NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

One thing to note here is that the result of the `-validate` method ***MUST*** be an `id`.  So if it returns a true/false value, it should return a `BOOL` boxed in an `NSNumber`.  (The `YES` in the predicate format string is automatically converted into an `NSNumber` for you)

Once you've got the predicate, you can set it into your array controller or whatever.